# Booting sequence in dual boot environment - Windows 7 + Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Until recently, I was able to progress without a problem in a single hard drive Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot environment. The boot menu would prompt whether one wanted to load Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04, with the default being Windows 7 ; this was possible by manipulating the boot menu using [EasyBCD's tool](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). If one were to select the Ubuntu 12.04 option, it would take one to GRUB from where Ubuntu 12.04 was loaded.

While fidgeting with something, I had to update GRUB with 'update-grub' command and now the booting sequence is reversed. On booting the computer, I now get the GRUB screen (with the default being Ubuntu 12.04) and if on selecting the Windows 7 option there manually, I get the original boot menu of either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04. Being a bit geeky, I can handle this ; however, the girlfriend is confused with the various turns and selections. How do I reset to the orginal state of the boot menu offering Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04, with Windows 7 as the default option ?

I cannot set the GRUB timeout to '0' as Ubuntu 12.04 would be selected by default, something I do not want. A possible option would be to push Windows 7 to the top of GRUB's list but this would still mean the the booting sequence would be GRUB --> Windows 7 to load Windows 7. Is there a remedy to bring back the original state of the boot menu offering Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04, with Windows 7 as the default option ?

A2Mail.

Answer (score 1):

This **sounds** like you've managed to chain-load two grubs together. Or perhaps one grub and one lilo ro something crazy like that.

I'd give boot-repair a go.